# Smallest containing simplex

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $V_n$ be the least real number such that for every convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with hypervolume $1$ there is a containing simplex with hypervolume $V_n$.
What is known about $V_n$? Is there a known general formula? If not, then what are the known best bounds for $V_n$?

Comment: Do you have an example with $V_2 > 2$?

Comment: No, I don't have one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem seems to be still open even for $n=3$:
 *Weisstein, Eric W. ["Tetrahedron Circumscribing."](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TetrahedronCircumscribing.html)*

Answer (score 8):

The paper [Parallelotopes of Maximum Volume in a Simplex](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00009432) by Lassak gives the maximum possible volume of a parallelotope in a simplex as $n!/n^n$ times the volume of the simplex. This gives us a bound of $V_n \geq n^n/n!$, which I suspect is tight.

Answer (score 2):

In the paper Minimum area of circumscribed polygons, in Elemente der Mathematik Vol. 28 (1973), Chakerian proved the following:

Any convex body K in Euclidean n-space is contained in a simplex T of volume not more than n^{n-1} times that of K.

Nothing is said there about the extremal cases, so it is possible that the bound is not tight.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.um.es/beca/NoLiFA/charlas/talk_Merzbacher_NoLiFA.pdf

Please check out these nice slides with lots of references; they get an asymptotic of root n.

Comment: To be clear, the asymptotic of $n^{1/2}$ is for $V_n^{1/n}$.